# Getting jSonOject error when running hadoop jar command

Tags: java, json, hadoop, mapreduce

Getting jSonOject error when running hadoop jar command

```
    ERROR="Error: java\.lang\.ClassNotFoundException: org\.json\.JSONObject

    15/04/01 18:44:17 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id :        attempt_201410201117_0915_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
    Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.JSONObject
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at
```

I have compiled the Java class through:

```
$ /usr/bin/javac -cp /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-4.7.0
-1.cdh4.7.0.p0.40/lib/*:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-4.7.0
-1.cdh4.7.0.p0.40/lib/hadoop/client-0.20/*:/opt/cloudera
/parcels/CDH-4.7.0-1.cdh4.7.0.p0.40/lib/hadoop/*:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-  4.7.0
-1.cdh4.7.0.p0.40/lib/org.json.jar/:/opt/cloudera/parcels/
CDH-4.7.0-1.cdh4.7.0.p0.40/lib/java-json.jar /var/lib/hadoophdfs/xxx
/multipleOutJsonEx/PartitionByMultipleOutputs.java
```

Even running the hadoop jar command with json jar file:

```
hadoop jar /var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/xxx/jarFiles/multipleoutputs.jar
PartitionByMultipleOutputs -libjars 
/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-4.7.0-1.cdh4.7.0.p0.40/lib/java-json.jar 
/user/xxx/multipleOutTest/json_input.txt /user/nchalasani/output
```

So not sure why I am still getting the error:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basically downloaded the json-20140107.jar and extracted it in the working folder

jar -xvf json-20140107.jar

once I did that. I compiled the java program. I didnt even mention the jsonJar file in the classpath.

Created JAR and executed it.

The key is to extract the json jar file which created org dir and and the created a whole new jar file included the classes and jsonJar.